# Put all words in a variable / dataframe and count number of times words showed up in a twitter dataframe in R

Tags: r, twitter, grepl

So I have 10k tweets and I want to be able to put all the words I want to look for in a variable  and count the number of times the words appeared across all tweets.

I have this but I don't want to copy and paste these 2 lines every time especially if I'm counting 50 words:

**Not an ideal Code:**

```
coffee    <- grepl("coffee", tweetsDF$text, ignore.case=TRUE)
sum(coffee) / nrow(text)

mug    <- grepl("mug", tweetsDF$text, ignore.case=TRUE)
sum(mug) / nrow(text)
```

Please help me have just one where I can just put all words in one frame.

**Expected Output:**

```
words     freq
coffee    50
mug       20
milk      67
juice     78
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply` to do this

```
out <- stack(lapply(setNames(words, words), function(x) 
      mean(grepl(x, tweetsDF$text, ignore.case = TRUE))))[2:1]
names(out) <- c("words", "perc")
```

-output

```
out
#   words perc
#1 coffee  0.4
#2    mug  0.6
```

#### Update

If the words to be checked are based on the file names read the files by looping over the file names in `lapply`, store the output in a `list` ('lst1'), then get the `sum` of logical vector from `grepl` that matches the corresponding file name in the 'text' column, `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
files <- c("coffee.csv", "mug.csv")
words <-  tools::file_path_sans_ext(files)
lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)
out_lst <- Map(function(x, y) sum(grepl(y, x$text,
          ignore.case = TRUE)), lst1, words)
names(out_lst) <- words
out <- stack(out_lst)
```

#### data

```
words <- c("coffee", "mug")
tweetsDF <- data.frame(text = c("mug shot", "mug2", "coffee pot",
        "mug3", "coffee stand"))
```

Comment: can you give me an example of how it would look like? Putting the words in words and counting

Comment: @KateLara do you want to count or get the percentage?  your code suggests percentage

Comment: So in terms of getting the data I have this:

tweets <- read.csv('coffee.csv', header=TRUE)
coffee    <- grepl("coffee", tweets$text, ignore.case=TRUE)
sum(mug) / nrow(text)

I don't think I understand how the data is collected from your end.

Comment: @KateLara I created an example data for 'tweets' just to test it.  In your case, you are reading the data from the 'tweets'. I assume that the words you check are some custom words

Comment: I'm getting the words from a csv file column with several rows of tweets - so not really just words, but rather tweets (sentences, phrases etc) and I want to count how many times the words showed up across that column.

Comment: I'm probably not explaining it clear. I've updated the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073470/grepl-group-of-strings-and-count-frequency-of-all-using-r