# Grepl group of strings and count frequency of all using R

Tags: r, count, grepl

I have a column of 50k rows of tweets named text from a csv file (the tweets consists of sentences, phrases etc). I'm trying to count frequency of several words in that column. Is there an easier way to do it vs what I'm doing below?

```
# Reading my file
tweets <- read.csv('coffee.csv', header=TRUE)


# Doing a grepl per word (This is hard because I need to look for many words one by one)
coffee    <- grepl("coffee", text$tweets, ignore.case=TRUE)
mugs    <- grepl("mugs", text$tweets, ignore.case=TRUE)


# Calculate the % of times among all tweets (This is hard because I need to calculate one by one)

sum(coffee) / nrow(text)
sum(starbucks) / nrow(text)
```

Expected Output (assuming I have more than 2 words up there)

```
Word   Freq
coffee  50
mugs    40
cup     64
pen     12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector of the words that you want to count frequency/percentage for and use `sapply` to calculate them.

```
words <- c('coffee', 'mugs')

data.frame(words, t(sapply(paste0('\\b', words, '\\b'), function(x) {
  tmp <- grepl(x, tweets$text)
  c(perc = mean(tmp) * 100, 
    Freq = sum(tmp))
})), row.names = NULL) -> result
result

#   words     perc Freq
#1 coffee 33.33333    1
#2   mugs 66.66667    2
```

`sapply` is similar to `for` loop as it iterates over each word defined in `words`. `grepl` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` values indicating if the word is present in `tweets$text` which is stored in `tmp`. To count the frequency we use `sum` and for percentage we use `mean`. Also added word boundary (`\\b`) to the words so that they match completely in the `text` hence `'coffee'` does not match with `'coffees'` etc.

**data**

```
tweets <- data.frame(text = c('This is text with coffee in it with lot of mugs', 
                              'This has only mugs', 
                              'This has nothing'))
```

Comment: HI Ronak! As for the getting the data, I have 50k tweets and I don't think putting it in vector c would work. How do I import it from Tweets.csv? (Column name: text)

Comment: You don't have to put data one by one in a vector. You already have the data `tweets <- read.csv('coffee.csv', header=TRUE)`. You need to put words that you want to count frequency for in the vector. `words <- c('coffee', 'mugs', 'cup', 'pen')`

Comment: Thank you that works! Can you explain what the lines of code in: data.frame ? Like what does sapply does and the tmp?

Comment: I added some explanation of the code in the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry one last question, what if I have like 2 words but I want to count them as one like: 'iced coffee'? Will that work do I have to make a gsub?

Comment: That will work as well without any change in the code, just include it in `words`. `words <- c('coffee', 'mugs', 'cup', 'pen', 'iced coffee')`